# SignalR Hub method only works in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a bizarre problem. Currently I'm working on some project that aims to remotely manage Docker containers in .net environment. The problem occurs when I try to execute some Docker Exec command in a container. I'm using Docker.DotNet library. It works as expected when I debug the code below step by step. But not when running without debugging. Any suggestions?

```
public async Task<string> SendAsync(string id, string command, bool tty = true)
    {
        var stream = await _mediator.Send(new StartContainerExecCommand() { ExecId = id, Tty = tty });
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);

        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, CancellationToken.None);
        stream.CloseWrite();

        var output = await stream.ReadOutputToEndAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        Console.WriteLine(output.stdout + " " + output.stderr);

        stream.Dispose();

        return output.stdout;
    }
```

Comment: It does not work "not when running without debugging" - what does this mean exactly? In your IDE without break points? Or in your Docker environment?
Can you tell what part of your code is executed? E.g. your `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I set a break point right before the line that goes "var stream = await...."  and if I press F10 repeteadly until the method returns it works as expected (outputs the result in Console.WriteLine). For example when I sent the command of "ls\n" from client side Console.Writeline successfuly prints the contents of the container in the debug console. But when I disable the break point or just run without debugging the Console.WriteLine won't print anything.

Comment: The question is still relevant @nilsK

Comment: Hi Furkan, my apologies, i was on vacation. To be honest, i don't really have any good ideas. Your code looks fine to me. What happens to your Task, when nothing gets printed? Does it run forever? No exceptions thrown? Did you try to try/catch your method calls (i.e. `_mediator.Send`, `stream.WriteAsync`, `stream.ReadOutputToEndAsync`) and print, if something gets caught?